# Reading QAudioProbe buffer

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyside, pyside2

The Qt documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtMultimedia/QAudioBuffer.html) says that we should read the buffer from QAudioProbe like this:

```
// With a 16bit sample buffer:
quint16 *data = buffer->data<quint16>(); // May cause deep copy
```

This is C++, but I need to write this in Python.

I am not sure how to use the Qt quint16 data type or even how to import it.

Here is my full code:

```
#!/bin/python3

from PySide2.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent, QAudioProbe, QAudioBuffer
from PySide2.QtCore import QUrl, QCoreApplication, QObject, Signal, Slot
import sys


def main():

    app = QCoreApplication()
    player = QMediaPlayer()
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile("/home/ubuntu/sound.wav")
    content = QMediaContent(url)
    player.setMedia(content)
    player.setVolume(50)

    probe = QAudioProbe()
    probe.setSource(player)
    probe.audioBufferProbed.connect(processProbe)

    player.play()


def processProbe(probe):
    print(probe.data())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
shiboken2.shiboken2.VoidPtr(Address 0x2761000, Size 0, isWritable False)
shiboken2.shiboken2.VoidPtr(Address 0x2761000, Size 0, isWritable False)
shiboken2.shiboken2.VoidPtr(Address 0x2761000, Size 0, isWritable False)
shiboken2.shiboken2.VoidPtr(Address 0x2761000, Size 0, isWritable False)
...
```

Comment: use `print(probe.data().toBytes())` but according to the log you show, it has a data of size 0.

Comment: See https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/PYSIDE/issues/PYSIDE-934?filter=allissues

Comment: That's disappointing. Do you know any other ways to show the loudness level of a WAV file in PySide2/Python?

Comment: I have the same problem, I try to use that byte_array = (ctypes.c_uint8 * length_array).from_address(buff.constData().__int__()) but with no result

Comment: @devdev comment on the bug to get attention from developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with a fresh `PySide2 5.13.2` environment, and running `print(probe.data().toBytes())` returned chunks of size 0 which I knew couldn't be the case because other built-in functionality was accessing the data.

I hate this hack as much as anyone else, but if you want to *test* things it is possible to access the buffer contents this way (please **do not use this in production code**):

1. Find out about the datatype, endian-ness etc of your buffer via [format](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtforpython-5.14/PySide2/QtMultimedia/QAudioFormat.html#PySide2.QtMultimedia.QAudioFormat), and infer the proper C type that you'll need (e.g. signed int 16).
2. Extract the printed address from the `VoidPtr` printout, and convert it to an integer
3. Create a numpy array by reading at the given address, with the given type, and by the given amount of frames.

---

### Code:

First of all, somewhere in your app, you'll be connecting your `QAudioProbe` to your source via `setSource`, and then the `audioBufferProbed` signal to a method e.g.:

```
self.audio_probe.audioBufferProbed.connect(self.on_audio_probed)
```

Then, the following `on_audio_probed` functionality will fetch the numpy array and print its norm, which should increase in presence of sound:

```py
import numpy as np
import ctypes

def get_buffer_info(buf):
    """
    """
    num_bytes = buf.byteCount()
    num_frames = buf.frameCount()
    #
    fmt = buf.format()
    sample_type = fmt.sampleType()  # float, int, uint
    bytes_per_frame = fmt.bytesPerFrame()
    sample_rate = fmt.sampleRate()
    #
    if sample_type == fmt.Float and bytes_per_frame == 4:
        dtype = np.float32
        ctype = ctypes.c_float
    elif sample_type == fmt.SignedInt and bytes_per_frame == 2:
        dtype = np.int16
        ctype = ctypes.c_int16
    elif sample_type == fmt.UnsignedInt and bytes_per_frame == 2:
        dtype = np.uint16
        ctype = ctypes.c_uint16
    #
    return dtype, ctype, num_bytes, num_frames, bytes_per_frame, sample_rate

def on_audio_probed(audio_buffer):
    """
    """
    cdata = audio_buffer.constData()
    (dtype, ctype, num_bytes, num_frames,
     bytes_per_frame, sample_rate) = get_buffer_info(audio_buffer)
    pointer_addr_str = str(cdata).split("Address ")[1].split(", Size")[0]
    pointer_addr = int(pointer_addr_str, 16)
    arr = np.array((ctype * num_frames).from_address(pointer_addr))
    print(np.linalg.norm(arr))  # should increase in presence of sound
```

---

I just tested it with a `QAudioRecorder` using 16-bit unsigned wavs, and it worked "fine" (audio looked and sounded good, see screenshot below). Again, this is basically a meme code so anything above showing your fancy audio buffered app to your cousins will be extremely risky, **do not use in serious code**. But in any case let me know if any other workarounds worked for you, or if this also worked in a different context! Hopefully if the devs see that people are actually using this approach they'll fix the issue much sooner :)

[image]

Cheers!
Andres

Comment: Glad it helps. Keep a close eye on it though. On my end it has been stable so far, serving for multiple days uninterrupted