# How to simply get audio amplitude in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a progress bar which will vary it's value dependent on the real time amplitude of my microphone (default input device). I believe the missing key here is to use QIODevice::readAll() but I do not understand how QIODevice works with QAudioInput.

```
QAudioInput *audio;
QAudioFormat formatAudio;
formatAudio.setSampleRate(8000);
formatAudio.setChannelCount(1);
formatAudio.setSampleSize(8);
formatAudio.setCodec("audio/pcm");
formatAudio.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
formatAudio.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);
QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
if (!info.isFormatSupported(formatAudio)) formatAudio = info.nearestFormat(formatAudio);

audio = new QAudioInput(formatAudio, this);
```

Comment: What's stopping you from calling audio->start() to get the QIODevice and then using that to invoke `read` calls on it?

Comment: I am missing the relationship between audio->start() and invoking read calls. Do I need to create a QByteArray object first so that the data is stored somewhere? or is it as simple as QIODevice::read()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create a QIODevice that is passed to the start() method (the solution is inspired by the official example [Audio Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-audio-example.html)).

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtMultimedia>

class Device: public QIODevice{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Device(QObject *parent=nullptr): QIODevice(parent)
    {
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void levelChanged(quint8 level);
protected:
    qint64 readData(char *data, qint64 maxSize) override
    {
        Q_UNUSED(data)
        Q_UNUSED(maxSize)
        return -1;
    }
    qint64 writeData(const char *data, qint64 maxSize) override
    {
        static const int resolution = 4;
        int s;
        for (s = 0; s < maxSize/resolution; ++s, data += resolution){
            quint8 level = static_cast<quint8>(*data);
            Q_EMIT levelChanged(level);
        }
        return maxSize;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QAudioFormat format;
    format.setSampleRate(8000);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(8);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);
    QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
        qWarning() << "Default format not supported, trying to use the nearest.";
        format = info.nearestFormat(format);
    }

    QAudioInput audio(format);

    Device device;
    device.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    audio.start(&device);

    QProgressBar progressbar;
    progressbar.setMaximum(256);
    progressbar.setFormat("%v");
    QObject::connect(&device, &Device::levelChanged, &progressbar, &QProgressBar::setValue);
    progressbar.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: This almost got me there. When I declare the instance of Device I must use a pointer: Device *device; Otherwise I get an abstract class error. So then I tried device->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly); and audio.start(device);     This leads to the program unexpectedly finishing.

Comment: @galeotron use `Device *device = new Device;`

Comment: I am still getting an error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'Device'

Comment: @galeotron What you say is strange, try my updated code, on the other hand, have you tested my code in a new project before integrating it into your project? I point it out so that your project does not add bugs that only complicate the application

Comment: @eyllanesc What's the difference between using QAudioProbe and QIODevice? Like in my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66417106/reading-qaudioprobe-buffer

Comment: @Aaron Conceptually in this case the QIODevice fulfills the function of the QAudioProbe, but the QIODevice cannot be used in QMediaPlayer unlike QAudioInput. QMediaPlayer is an implementation that allows to have the same API of the different libraries that handle the audio and video files, unlike QAudioInput reads the data from the sound card through the system libraries.